# How can I call a GUI nested in EventQueue.invokeLater from the exterior?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

How can I call a GUI element from the exterior?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            gui = new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    gui.textarea.something;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: My project contain two modules: a gui interface and a logic controller. I want do same changes from logical controller which is outside.

Answer (score 0):

I also think this is an XY Problem.  However, to answer the narrow question you have asked, just invoke `invokeLater()` a second time.  I think perhaps the problem may just be the need to store the variable `gui` for later.  The simple answer is that you just store it as normal, but NEVER access it from anywhere except the EDT.

```
public class MyApp {

   // Never access except from the EDT
   private static Object gui;

   public static void main(String args[]) {
     java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            gui = new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    // ... time passes ...


    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           gui.textarea.something;
        }
    } );
  }
}
```

---

Re. your comment:

If you're asking about modules, you are probably looking at some form of Dependency Injection.  One way to do this is to make a special holder object to hold context information for your application.  There's about a zillion ways to do this.  Here's a simple one to get you started.  A better method might be to use more, smaller context objects that refer to smaller portions of the application.

```
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
     GuiContext guic = new GuiContext();
     java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        final GuiContext guiCtx = guic;
        public void run() {
            gui = new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            guiCtx.setMainFrame( gui );
        }
    });
    MyModule mod = new MyModule( guic );
    mod.startMessage();
}


public class MyModule  {
   private GuiContext gui;
   public MyModule( GuiContext gui ) { this.gui = gui; }
   public void startMessage() {
      gui.setMessage( "hello" );
   }
}

public class GuiContext {
   private Window gui;
   public setGui( Window gui ) { this.gui = gui; }
   public setMessage( final String message ) {
     java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            gui.add( message );
        }      
     } );
   }
}
```